# How to add symbol " to a String?

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to add this symbol **"** to a `String` or print to console?
I'm using it for my `ImageIcon`! file path thanks!

Comment: Down voters care to share a reason?  Even if naive, this is a simple and direct question.  If 'lack of research' is the reason, try finding a duplicate on SO.  Even with `[java] [string] escape` I was not seeing obvious hits on the first page of results.  And note of course that **`escape`** in that search was 90% of the answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks Andrew I did use quite a reasonable amount of time researching for it but I am a newbie and I seriously can't find anything which helps. Cheers. :)

Comment: I don't doubt it for a moment.  Anything involving `"` is difficult to search/research!  Google ignores it completely.

Comment: Too lazy to search............

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need to escape the character with `\` for Java to understand it:

```
String quote = "\"";
```

Comment: thanks oh by the way, where can i find information about this symbol stuff? :)

Comment: The first official source I can find is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

To be able to include " in a Java String you need to escape it like this

```
String s = "this is a String containing \" which is escaped by backslash"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way that was not mentioned here is the use of a char object.

```
String quote1 = (char)'"';
String quote2 = (char)34;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean How to print "Hello World" text on console? If yes then you can do that like this:

```
System.out.print("\"Hello World\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="Prashant"+"*^%$#@!\" ";
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to add before it the Escape character .